# Is it possible to change the block target time?

Tags: mining, private-blockchain

We're curious to know what factors go into block times in a private network with a limited number of validators. Is this fixed or can it be parameterized in any way? How is it related to block times in the public net?

Answer (score 14):

The block times in a private network and the public network is determined by the block difficulty adjustment algorithm. This algorithm is fixed in code, and is examined in more detail in [How does the Ethereum Homestead difficulty adjustment algorithm work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/how-does-the-ethereum-homestead-difficulty-adjustment-algorithm-work/5914#5914)

You can find the source code that represents this algorithm in [block_validator.go, lines 265-312](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/core/block_validator.go#L265-L312). You will have to modify this algorithm/code to change the block target time.

You can set the genesis block difficulty in your private network using the [init](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#init) parameter, but the difficulty will eventually be adjusted according to the algorithm described above.