# How to make Ethereum mining difficulty static for a private chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, testnets, difficulty

I have implemented private chain in ethereum but its difficulty level increases by time as a result the mining process slows down. Is it possible to make the difficulty static or disable it in testnet.

Comment: Here you can see the whole explanation to do it:
http://blog.coinfabrik.com/fast-smart-contracts-execution-ethereum-private-blockchain-development-environment/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Modify the `CalcDifficulty` in Geth to return a static number, then rebuild Geth.  Example:

```
func CalcDifficulty(config *ChainConfig, time, parentTime uint64, parentNumber, parentDiff *big.Int) *big.Int {
    return big.NewInt(0x4000)
}
```

Source: [Answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7142/42) to [Is it possible to change the block target time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7141/is-it-possible-to-change-the-block-target-time/7142)

Comment: Is this still the only way to decrease the difficulty?

Comment: @ThorkilVærge I usually won't answer/reply if I don't know.  But I'm doing so here since I'm not ignoring the question, and would encourage if there are new answers.

Answer (score 2):

If it is private chain you can define `difficulty` in genesis block.

Something like this

```
{
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "difficulty": "0x4000",
    "alloc": {},
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "Custem Ethereum Genesis Block",
    "gasLimit": "0xffffffff"
}
```

Here is a good read to [How to Set up testnet](https://lightrains.com/blogs/setup-local-ethereum-blockchain-private-testnet)

Comment: I have used this format only. Initially the mining is fast but as the time flows the difficulty increases and mining goes very slow.

Comment: The difficulty is adjusted automatically so the average block time is within the hard-coded time in ethereum. The difficulty you specify in the genesis file is just the starting difficulty. To make difficulty static you need to modify the source code.

Comment: @dragosb yeah, but OP is not asking for the dynamic settings.

Comment: what genesis block has to do with difficulty as it is only to create inital blockchain . difficulty is measured by  CalcDifficulty algo.

Comment: @Himanshusharma I understand that. OP is asking about creating the initial set up.