# Making difficulty static - Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, poa, difficulty

I made a setup for a private PoA network with geth. Everything works fine, regarding mining, making transactions, connecting through http and websockets. Now I need to optimize transaction time, I need to make it as fast as possible. As already known, difficulty is one of the most important things which can cause blocks to be mined slowly. They have their very important purpose, but for me is more important to have fast transactions.

Therefore I tried to change difficulty in genesis.json file, but of course difficulty keeps increasing, and mining is slower and slower. I want to make difficulty completely static(not changeable). I already tried:

- [How to make Ethereum mining difficulty static for a private chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/how-to-make-ethereum-mining-difficulty-static-for-a-private-chain)
- [How to reduce block difficulty in ethereum private testnet](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-reduce-block-difficulty-in-ethereum-private-testnet-2ad505609e82)

The thing is that difficulty keeps increasing, much slower but keeps increasing. For me I need a network where there is no delay because of this thing at all.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a PoA network? PoA networks have a fixed block time. If all validators are online it should take the same time for all the blocks. Perhaps you need to increment the block gas limit, so more transactions will fit in a block.

Comment: can you share your genesis file? which client are you using?