# How many miners are necessary for correct private blockchain work?

Tags: private-blockchain, miner

Can we calculate the number of miners,that we will need in private blockchain in advance and how?
for POW algorithm

Comment: What do you mean "in advance"? I would think at least one, but to protect against him going offline the actual number should probably be higher. That depends entirely on your preferences.

Comment: what do you mean by correct?? you mean secure?

Comment: @Badr Bellaj  I mean secure,faster mining and fault tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

1 miner is all it takes on a private blockchain, as the difficulty of mining a block is adjusted so that the average sits between 10 - 19 seconds, as described in ["How does the Ethereum Homestead difficulty adjustment algorithm work?"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/how-does-the-ethereum-homestead-difficulty-adjustment-algorithm-work/5914#5914).

If you are worried blocks will be mined too slowly, you can change the initial mining difficulty on your private chain as described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7141/is-it-possible-to-change-the-block-target-time/7142#7142):

> You can set the genesis block difficulty in your private network using the [init](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#init) parameter, but the difficulty will eventually be adjusted according to the algorithm described above.