# How can I get MHash value when ethminer doesn't provide one?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethminer, hashrate

In order to set up the ethminer I need the MHash value. I'm testing CPU, so I ran:

```
ethminer -M
```

and I got a weird output:

```
Trial 1... 0
Trial 2... 0
Trial 3... 0
Trial 4... DAG  17:33:59.896|miner0  Generating DAG file. Progress: 0 %
0
Trial 5... 0
 ⚡   17:34:04.302|ethminer  Terminate worker 500 ms
min/mean/max: 0/0/0 H/s
inner mean: 0 H/s
Phoning home to find world ranking...
```

I have the DAG file generated and everything should be set up (I tried to mine setting a number and it did report hashes per second and stuff). So I'm not sure if the -M switch is not working properly or I'm doing something wrong, and I need the mhash value so I don't mess it up and end up losing money.

Thank you.

Comment: Can reproduce this, probably a bug. I also get 0 H/s using `-M`.

Comment: I read on another forum (irrelevant to mining) that some GPUs take time to warm up. Try running your benchmark with `--benchmark-warmup 10`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use chfast's Fakeminer to do cpu benchmarks, see https://github.com/chfast/ethash/tree/master/test/fakeminer

Answer (score 0):

> -M,--benchmark  Benchmark for mining and exit; use with --cpu and --opencl.

Try with `ethminer -M --cpu` or `ethminer -M --opencl` depending on CPU / GPU benchmarking.

**Edit** :
For some reason `-M -G` gives 0 hashrate while `-G -M` works. The ordering should ideally not matter, but maybe it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try mining on a private Ethereum blockchain and look at how long it takes you to mine blocks as the difficulty rises. The hashing speed can then be calculated as `hash_rate = difficulty / block_time_in_seconds`. Alternately, you can mine on a pool or the test net (but I believe etiquette dictates you shouldn't mine on the test net for too long if you have an sizeable mining capacity -- which should be fine given you're testing a CPU). Pool mining is potentially less accurate.

See also [How do I decrease the difficulty on a private testnet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/how-do-i-decrease-the-difficulty-on-a-private-testnet) if you want to try a private blockchain.