# Can unlock account, but not send transaction

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, accounts

I've compiled a version of geth where I modified CalcDifficulty() in *core/block_validator.go* to make mining difficulty constant, see [reference](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/how-do-i-decrease-the-difficulty-on-a-private-testnet). Starting up the private chain, creating accounts and mining works fine.

If I try via the javascript console to unlock an account, it works, and returns **true**.

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])

But when I try to send a transaction:

> personal.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1],
>   value: 20000000})

I get the following:

```
Error: could not decrypt key with given passphrase
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: can confirm, I'm also seeing this issue. also on a testnet, without having modified my geth client (Geth/v1.6.6-stable-10a45cb5/linux-amd64/go1.8.1)

Comment: I raised this geth bug https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`personal.sendTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_sendtransaction) method expects a second argument, the password to ephemerally unlock the account with and send the transaction in one go. If you don't provide a password, this endpoint defaults to the empty password, resulting in your issue.

If you want to use an already unlocked account to send a transaction (instead of the ephemeral unlock-and-send), you can do so with `eth.sendTransaction`.